# What to do with old air/light shaft?

Tags: bathroom, vent, renovation

I live in an old house that is very narrow but tall. In the middle it features an old air/light shaft that looks very similar to [this one](http://pinkbrownstone.com/2012/07/14/the-airlight-shaft/). It goes through attic room, second floor bathroom, first floor bathroom down to basement/laundry room.

What do I do with it?

Ideally I would love to somehow "extend" the bathroom floors to make use of the shaft space  (the bathrooms are miniature).

Or I was thinking of putting in modern [light tunnels](http://www.sterlingbuild.co.uk/products/Sun-Tunnels) to bring at least some daylight to the miniature bathrooms. Though I am not sure how efficient will the light tunnels be on the distance of 2-3 floors.

Or I was thinking of putting in some king of slide for laundry that would connect all the floors with a laundry room in the basement. But I was unable to google anything so laundry slide is probably not the correct term.

Any other ides? Any advice is welcome.

Comment: The proper US term is "laundry chute". We had one in the house I grew up in and it was pretty awesome.

Comment: Question the "servant era practice" of sending laundry to the basement and then hauling clean laundry upstairs. If the laundry machines are on the same floor as the bedrooms, there's a lot of hauling laundry around that you (or your spouse) don't have to do.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Actually that is a great point, but there is really no space for washing machine or drying laundry on the living floors. The laundry chute can at least half the hauling.

Answer (score 1):

To get the floorspace and **some** light, I guess you could paint the attic section brilliant white, or mirror-line it (the light-pipe idea without restricting the size to the size of the light-pipes - perhaps using builders aluminum foil) put a "skylight" on it in the upper bathroom ceiling and put floor-load and fire-rated glass panels in the bathroom floors. Save a corner of the shaft-space for ventilation duct if there is not an independent means of ventilation for these bathrooms.

One reason for the decline of laundry chutes (however awesome they are ;^) ) is that they are a fire hazard (or a fire traveling quickly through your house hazard, more accurately) as a big penetration in the floor assemblies - to a fire, it looks like a chimney.

If keeping it a a chute, I guess you could still get some light and reduce lost socks by making the walls mostly glass.